# Recursively create Graph from seed and Nest GraphUnion, keeping VertexStyle, EdgeLabels, VertexCoordinates, EdgeShapeFunction

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, iteration, automation, properties

## TL;DR;

[`GraphUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphUnion.html) does not preserve properties of the input `Graph`s.

**How do I combine two `Graph` preserving and/or modifying properties?**

## Detail

I want to recursively create a [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) from a `seed`, [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and a `grow` function using [`GraphUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphUnion.html) (or similar), preserving the `seed` properties on  [`VertexStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexStyle.html), [`EdgeLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeLabels.html), [`VertexCoordinates`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html), [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html).

For example, let's say I have the following `seed`

```
esf =   {
            Line[{Transpose[#1].{0.97, 0.03}, Transpose[#1].{0.55,0.45}}],
            Arrow[{Transpose[#1].{0.45,0.55}, Transpose[#1].{0.02,0.98} }]
        }&


seed = Graph[
      {1, 2}
    , { DirectedEdge[1, 2] }
    , VertexStyle -> { 1 -> Red, 2 -> Blue }
    , EdgeLabels -> { DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> 1 }
    , VertexCoordinates -> { {-1, 0}, {+0, 0} }
    , EdgeShapeFunction -> esf
]
```

[image]

The `grow` function will take a `Graph` and join it with a modified copy of itself.

something like

```
grow[gr_Graph]:= GraphUnion[
    gr
    , IndexGraph[gr, VertexCount[gr]+1 ]  (* Modified Graph *)
    , Graph[                    (* New edge connects two Graphs*)
        DirectedEdge[
            VertexCount[gr],
            2*VertexCount[gr]
        ]
    ]
]
```

but with some modification. Example `mod` modifications could be:

- Increment `EdgeLabels`
- Change `VertexStyle`
- [`TransformationFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunction.html) `VertexCoordinates`

But if I do

```
grow[seed]

(* Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[3, 4], DirectedEdge[2, 4]}]] *)
```

[image]

It drops all information about `VertexStyle`, `EdgeLabels`, `VertexCoordinates`, `EdgeShapeFunction`.

I would like the output of `grow[seed]` to be something around

```
Graph[
    {1, 2, 3, 4}
    ,
    {
        DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[3, 4], DirectedEdge[2, 4]
    }
    , VertexStyle -> 
        {
            1 -> Red
          , 2 -> Blue
          , 3 -> Lighter[Red]    (* Original colour modified *)
          , 4 -> Lighter[Blue]   
        }
    , EdgeLabels -> 
        {
             DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> 1,
             DirectedEdge[3, 4] -> 1,
             DirectedEdge[2, 4] -> 2     (* New edge increments label *)
        }
    , VertexCoordinates ->               (* TransformationFunction *) 
        {
            {-1, -1}
          , {-1,  0}
          , { 0, -1}
          , { 0,  0}
        }
    , EdgeShapeFunction -> esf
]
```

[image]

So I can later do things like

```
Nest[grow, seed, 6]
```

## Question

**How do I combine two `Graph` preserving and/or modifying properties?**

**How do I extract and modify properties of a `Graph` ?**

Comment: Easiest way is to supply `Options` to the `Graph` constructor. Here's how you inherit the shape function ``Graph[grow[seed], Options[seed, {EdgeShapeFunction}]]``. All other options can be added as normal.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1, that means that basically I need to rewrite `GraphUnion` to `Merge` all `Options` by hand. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm thinking at this stage that my `seed` may need to be an `Association` instead of a `Graph` to avoid all this pain.